# MVVM Application not Restoring State Correctly

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro, avalondock

I have built a class library that acts as a GUI framework that can be inherited by other projects. This application is based on projects [Wild](https://github.com/chandramouleswaran/Wide) and [Gemini](https://github.com/tgjones/gemini).

My problem is that upon restoring Avalon Dock's layout using the standard serializer

```
var layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(manager);
```

where `manager` is type `DockingManager`. The manager restores and empty tab. My guess is that Caliburn Micro cannot find the stored ViewModel (named `HomeViewModel`). However, I am struggling to confirm this.

I believe my bootstrapper to be correct and that the MEF containers are being setup correctly to allow resolution of external types. I have debugged the project to a point where I think this issue is occurring and in the output window I can see `Attach(Home)` where the attach is occurring (note, "Home" is the display name of the `HomeViewModel`). However, I don't know what is wrong with the attach process as this is handled by MEF/Caliburn.

I am really stuck with debugging this an wondered if

1. Any one could offer any insightful advice as to how to proceed with the debugging process?
2. Anyone would be willing to take a look at the solution?

I have spent a hell of a lot of time debugging this without any luck and the problem is sufficiently esoteric and illusive as to render most posts here irrelevant to me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: a working sample which can reproduce the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @pushpraj, thanks very much for your reply. This one is killing me! Here is a link to the GUI portion of the project http://1drv.ms/1A4v40R. It is not the smallest as I have include the packages folder as well. If you could help me out I would be willing to provide rep to you. Also, once you have downloaded this, could you let me know so I can lock it. Thanks very much...

Comment: If you build the project and run it, you will see that a "Home" tab gets opened. Now, by default all `Documents` object or to be more exact `LayoutItemBase` objects have their `ShouldReopenOnStartup` property set to false. But if you close the application down having the "Home" tab open, `ApplicationState.bin` gets created and you will see that the `HomeViewModel` gets written to the documents that were open. Now, when the program starts back up this items should not be restored, but it is. My thoughts here are that the type is not getting found by MED/CaliburnMicro...

Comment: Which is causing a blank type to be restored. I have taken this machanism for opening and closing documents from [Gemini](https://github.com/tgjones/gemini) because there were some bug in performing the restore in the recommended way. The opening strategy I use should be identical to Gemini's and Gemini's works fine. This is why I believe this could be a resolution issue. Do you think you could take a look at this? I will add a bounty to this question in due course.

Comment: I have downloaded the project, you may lock the same. Allow me some time to have a look. it's bit late over here, I hope you wont mind if I come up tomorrow.

Comment: Hey, I don't mind at all. I just really appreciate you taking a look, so thanks very much indeed! I am really stuck with this one, so appreciate all the help I can get... All the best and thanks again.

Comment: Is there anything else I may help you with?

Comment: No that's great for now. Thanks. Bounty awarded...

Comment: That's great! you may always find me through my profile. last but not the least happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as discussed and after looking on the sample code provided, I understand that the following

- `HomeViewModel` or can say `LayoutItemBase` is not supposed to be reopened as `ShouldReopenOnStartup` is set to false
- if you close the application while leaving a document open for HomeViewModel it is restored on next start with blank view [Not OK]

**Analysis**

the `SaveState` method was correctly honoring `ShouldReopenOnStartup` value and was not emitting the state for the `HomeViewModel` but dock manager was still emitting an element for the document.

So upon next restart the `LoadState` does not find any stored state but a window was created as an element was present in the dock manager's layout state

```
  <LayoutDocument Title="HomePP" IsSelected="True" IsLastFocusedDocument="True" ContentId="d716f824-cfff-4b54-8fd6-2d026a99369a" .../>
```

you did try to use e.Cancel property of Serialization callback to cancel the event, but seems like it is not supposed to prevent of loading a window but just simply to cancel the event if not needed.

**Resolution**

So the ideal approach is to close the documents which are not supposed to be restored before saving the layout

here is how I did

`ShellViewmodel.cs : Line 279` method `SaveState(string)`

change the following code

```
    if (!item.ShouldReopenOnStartup)
        continue;
```

to

```
    if (!item.ShouldReopenOnStartup)
    {
        //this item is not supposed to be restored so close the window before saving layout
        IDocument doc = item as IDocument;
        if (doc != null)
            CloseDocument(doc);
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a look at this. This is a good compromise. My confusion comes from the fact that the deserialisation callback does not seem to cancel correctly. Moreover, it is not clear where the blank `IDocument` is being instansiated during the load state operations; it is not the fact that the `ShouldReopenOnStartup` is being ignored, more as to why the restored `HomeViewModel` is blank. It seems that MEF cannot resolve this `Export`. This code I inherited from Gemini and at this stage I might rewrite as much of it is to deal with a bug that I do not have a problem with (yet).

Comment: Again, thanks very much for your time. I will award you a bounty for the time you have taken in due course (13 hours @ 10:06 GMT)...

Comment: I am glad to be your assistance, appreciate your gratitude at the same time. I also want to highlight that it is not a blank IDocument, but it is a dock manager's `layout element` which hosts the IDocument as content. this layout element does get stored in the application state file via `layoutSerializer.Serialize(stream)` and also gets restored back when you deserialize the state via `layoutSerializer.Deserialize(stream)`. secondly ShouldReopenOnStartup is a `custom property` from gambit framework, so layout manager may not be able to recognize the same.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification, that make much more sense now. I think your solution is a reasonable one and one I might adopt. What I suppose is confusing me, it that this part of the code I have literately copied from Gemini and it works fine for the Gemini project - I was getting bogged down in trying to work out the difference rather than rolling a solution of my own - silly really. What made me copy the Gemini stuff rather than writing my own is that this project seems to correct some well known issues with AvalonDock state files, so I thought why not use it. All the best and thanks...

Comment: That's great! you can always find me from my profile if needed. happy coding :)